# Simple SQL Server query clarification on finding a record using two conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm pretty new to SQL and would like some help with the following question:
What query would I run to find records that have a first name of "John" AND a last name of "Doe"?

[image: Here's a sample Table image]

If I try this, it doesn't work:

```
select * from tableNames
where (FName = 'John') and (LName = 'Doe')
```

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. What results do you get?

Comment: What error message do you get? Or does it just return no records? Is your table really called 'tableNames' ?

Comment: How does it "not work" - doesn't produce a result? Produces wrong results? Gives an error ? (if so: **what** error??)

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? everything is correct unless you are trying something different or you tableNames is not correct table name

Comment: You might have some leading spaces, tabs, carriage returns or some trailing tabs/carriage returns  in the values that messes things up? What does `select cast(Fname as varbinary(20)), cast(Lname as varbinary(20)) from tableNames where id in (1,3) ` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following *(exact same)* query as yours give the results you specify.

```
    ;WITH q AS (
      SELECT ID = 1, Fname = 'John', Lname = 'Doe'
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Barry', 'Singer'
      UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'John', 'Doe'
      UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'James', 'Brown'
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    q
    WHERE   Fname = 'John' AND Lname = 'Doe'
```

**Results**

```
 ID          Fname Lname  
 ----------- ----- ------ 
           1 John  Doe    
           3 John  Doe    
(2 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your query should work. Are you sure you have typed the table name correctly? What error are you receiving? This should also work, just replace `tableName` with the name of your table:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Fname = 'John' AND LName = 'Doe'
```

Here's an [interactive example](http://ideone.com/clone/W4ePc) showing that your original query *should* work.

Comment: @Downvoter: May I ask why I have been downvoted when my answer clearly answers the question that OP's code is correct, and also provides a valid working example proving correct functionality? I will also take this time to point out that if I was downvoted for writing something similar to the OP, then why hasn't Lieven's post also been downvoted when he clearly points out `Following (exact same) query as yours`?

Comment: I down voted because your re-posted the OP query and the rest of your content seemed more like a comment than an answer.  However, I didn't check out your link which actually seems pretty cool and provides what might pass as an answer.  After checking that out I tried to undo my down vote but it has been too long.  If you edit your question, I will undo it.

Comment: Edited. Thanks. I could have posed this as a comment, but since it was a bit longer I decided on using an answer.

Comment: I have no clue what happened. I just restarted sql server '08 and it works fine. Thanks very much for your response and the interactive link as well!

Comment: @Ray: Good! I'm glad you found your solution. Sometimes hardware/software just needs a reboot.