# Is there an online tool to build simple tables and test SQL statements?

Tags: sql

I want to be able to create simple tables and run SQL queries on them. I'm talking tables with fewer than 12 items. Is there an online tool to do this? This might seem crazy, but it'd really help as I go between 3-4 computers a day.

Example:

```
Cats
Cat Names | Age
Marsha    | 5
Melon     | 3

Select * from Cats where Age > 3

Marsha    | 5
```

Obviously that's a very, very simple example ... but I'm looking more towards testing some trickier SQL statements.

Edit: Not doing support. Right now I'm doing training and presentations. Screen sharing is not an option.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you interested in with this? Obviously you could be writing ANSI SQL, but perhaps there's a particular RDBMS you wanted?

Comment: I saw someone [post this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665184/simple-sql-server-query-clarification-on-finding-a-record-using-two-conditions/5665205#comment-6466363). Seems like it might do what you need? [http://ideone.com/clone/W4ePc](http://ideone.com/clone/W4ePc)

Comment: Something like this: http://www.sqlcourse.com/cgi-bin/interpreter.cgi?

Comment: Something like this also : http://www.oraclebin.com/2013/01/how-to-execute-sql-queries-online.html

Comment: I think this should be re-opened and migrated to SoftwareRecs.SE

Comment: I found this online editor very useful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just found this tool today:

[ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/W4ePc)

It lets you choose from a number of languages (including SQL), write your code and then execute it.  Pretty cool

Thanks to [FreeAsInBeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632736/freeasinbeer) for pointing me towards it.

Answer (score 23):

try [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) - it allows you to build your own schema and supports multiple vendors.

[rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode) supports [Sql Server](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler), [Oracle](http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler), [PostgreSQL](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) and [MySQL](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler)

Comment: SQL Fiddle is much more specifically aimed at SQL than IDEone, but execution is really slow - ~5 seconds for a simple SELECT out of a table with 5 records.

Comment: 2 msec for my queries. Maybe they improved it in the meantime? not sure why is crossed here

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in using Oracle, you could sign up for a free workspace at [http://apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html).  That is intended to give you the ability to try out Oracle's Application Express (APEX) product but the APEX development environment (all web based) does have places where you can create tables, insert data, etc.  This has the nice side effect of letting you persist the data over time.  And, you may find that you enjoy using APEX to build web apps as well.

See steps of creating account on Apex here

http://www.oraclebin.com/2013/01/how-to-execute-sql-queries-online.html

Comment: This is by far the best option!